# How to localize the timeline in DevExpress ASPxScheduler

Tags: localization, devexpress

I'am using DevExpress ASPxScheduler and I want to change the text I've pointed out to something like: [some_localized_text][1-4]

Is it possible, and how can I make it work?

[image: DevExpress ASPxScheduler problem]

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: Ok, thank You for -1, I've talked with DevExpress support and the answer is here: [link](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q332328)